# How to customize batch encryption in ShardingSphere-JDBC Encryption

Tags: java

In ShardingSphere ,how to customize the encryption algorithm to achieve batch encryption in ‘EncryptAlgorithm’ and ‘QueryAssistedEncryptAlgorithm’ class. Currently, both ‘EncryptAlgorithm’ and ‘QueryAssistedEncryptAlgorithm’ just supply methods such as below:

```
public String encrypt(Object o)

public Object decrypt(String s)
```

now, I want to refactor the interface to refactor bathch encrypt similar to ：

```
public String encrypt(List<String> encryptList)

public Object decrypt(List<String> decryptList)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks interesting. Could I know why you want to extend this interface?

From my understanding, ShardingSphere calls this interface for each column-value to encrypt and decrypt it as a unit, e.g, `tel` = `123`, since ShardingSphere will parse your SQL, split a `Where condition` into many such units which will be handled by this interface iteratively.

So, sorry I have no idea why you want to have a parameter `List<String> decryptList`. Thanks.